# Can't import JSON in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm having what I'm sure it's a stupid problem but I can't seem to find a way around it.

I have a react application and I'm trying to import a JSON file. Here it is:

```
{ 
   "words":{ 
      "ita":[ 
         "ora",
         "via",
         "dio",
         "sud",
         "don",
         "zia"
      ]
   }
}
```

And here's the react code:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'

import words from 'Assets/Words.json'

console.log(words)
console.log(words.ita)

export default class WordsGen extends Component {
  ...
```

The two `console.log` print, respectively:

```
{words: {…}}
  words:
    ita: (6) ["ora", "via", "dio", "sud", "don", "zia"]
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

and `undefined`.

I'm using the json file to put more languages in the app, but I can't understand why when I print just `words` I can see the property `ita` inside, and when I try to print `words.ita` or `words["ita"]` I get undefined.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be:

```
words.words.ita
```

You are importing as "words" and then the object has a words object. It might be more clear to change the import name:

```
import MyJson from 'my.json';

console.log(MyJson.words.ita)
```

Comment: In theory, you could also use object spreading to import it with `import { words } from 'my.json'`. Then it could be used as the author intended (`words.ita`).

Answer (score 0):

Because your imported object `words` contains whole json. When you write

```
import words from 'Assets/Words.json';
```

it will become

```
words = { 
   words:{ 
      ita:[ 
         "ora",
         "via",
         "dio",
         "sud",
         "don",
         "zia"
      ]
   }
}
```

That's why your object `words` doesn't really have property `ita`. That's why it will return `undefined`.

You need to write `words.words.ita`. For better code-style:

```
/// words.json
{ 
   "ita":[ 
       "ora",
       "via",
       "dio",
       "sud",
       "don",
       "zia"
      ]
}
```

```
import words from 'Assets/Words.json';
words.ita // then your code

/// or even better with new es6 destructing
import {ita = []} from 'Assets/Words.json';

ita // do anything that you want
```